# Sql Server Multiple Order?

Tags: sql-server

[image]

My table name is `Skor`..  `Skor` means "point", `sure` means "time" --- Max Point Min Time  (Multiple Order)

I want to order this table. But skor(MAX) value and sure(MIN) value and userID must be only one as you see there is 6 userID ( 2 ) I want the only max value

I want something like this

```
userID  skor   sure
  2       90    50
  3       90    60
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `userId` 2 doesn't have a `skor` of 90 in your example data? The `max` for that user is 95. I have no idea what you are asking here.

Comment: @Martin - neither does 3

Comment: I'm confused by your expected results. skorID 79 shows a skor value of 95 for userID 2, so why does your expected results show 90? I also do not see a sure value of 50 anywhere for userID 2. Also, I see no skor value of 90 for userID 3 in your sample data, the max appears to be 55.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT UserID, MAX(skor) as 'skor', MIN(sure) as 'sure'
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY UserID
```

This is assuming you want the max and min per user, not on the same record row.

Comment: SELECT userid, max(skor), min(sure)
    FROM tablename
    GROUP BY userid

this is not what I want..
![enter image description here][1]

 I want like this table...
I hope You guys know What I say:(

![enter image description here][2]


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/qrEIv.jpg
  [2]: http://i.imgur.com/YvZsP.jpg

Comment: @user - this query will give you **EXACTLY** what is in the picture you posted a link to.  The `MAX Skor` and `MIN sure` for each `USERID`, with only one row per `UserID`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a GROUP BY to your query on the userID column.
Eg.

```
DECLARE @Skor AS TABLE(userID int, skor int, sure int)

INSERT INTO @Skor(userID, skor, sure) VALUES (2,45,30)
INSERT INTO @Skor(userID, skor, sure) VALUES (2,30,25)
INSERT INTO @Skor(userID, skor, sure) VALUES (18,5,50)
INSERT INTO @Skor(userID, skor, sure) VALUES (18,10,50)
INSERT INTO @Skor(userID, skor, sure) VALUES (15,5,45)
INSERT INTO @Skor(userID, skor, sure) VALUES (15,50,60)
INSERT INTO @Skor(userID, skor, sure) VALUES (9,80,100)
INSERT INTO @Skor(userID, skor, sure) VALUES (10,70,40)
INSERT INTO @Skor(userID, skor, sure) VALUES (17,110,50)
INSERT INTO @Skor(userID, skor, sure) VALUES (3,55,60)
INSERT INTO @Skor(userID, skor, sure) VALUES (4,90,80)
INSERT INTO @Skor(userID, skor, sure) VALUES (6,65,90)
INSERT INTO @Skor(userID, skor, sure) VALUES (8,120,40)
INSERT INTO @Skor(userID, skor, sure) VALUES (2,80,60)
INSERT INTO @Skor(userID, skor, sure) VALUES (2,95,80)
INSERT INTO @Skor(userID, skor, sure) VALUES (2,5,80)
INSERT INTO @Skor(userID, skor, sure) VALUES (2,15,79)

SELECT userID, MAX(skor), MIN(sure)
FROM @Skor
GROUP BY userID
```

Comment: But my values inserting from asp.net page..  

I want Like This  http://i.imgur.com/YvZsP.jpg

Comment: the only thing I can think of as missing is an alias for each field...try this SELECT userID, MAX(skor) AS skor, MIN(sure) as sure FROM @Skor GROUP BY userID